# WebView Iframe Video

Tags: javascript, android, html, flash

I'm trying to upload this video(http://canalcamp.xiptv.cat/embed/234425?width=300&iframe_width=320&share=&height=170&iframe_height=200#), but I can not make out the controlling tabs (pause, volume, zoom,progress video).

I'm activating the javascript no way.

Note: Contains divix

This is my code :

```
 final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display=gone; " +
                        "})()");
            }
        });
        webview.clearCache(true);

        webview.clearHistory();
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl("http://canalcamp.xiptv.cat/embed/234425?width=300&iframe_width=320&share=&height=170&iframe_height=200#");
```

Also not work the "Share"

Comment: Upload?? But its already uploaded to canalcamp.xiptv.cat server already isnt it? Maybe you mean download (**get from**)? Also your `Note: Contains divix` I dont think divix or even DivX is supported on Android so you wont see anything. If there is a pcture/sound chances are that server gives MP4 not DivX AVI file. The controls & player are made with Flash. Problem is **No Flash-plugin for mobile browsers** allowed anymore so your webview cannot show it. If you need it badly find the direct link to video file and just play that FLV or MP4 file yourself without flash embed etc

Comment: Can you put any example full about this problem ? thanks

Comment: That link is a flash embed. No Flash plugin for android browser. Either make your `.apk` in Flash using AS3 language or forget it. Also you need to find the full video file link ending with `.mp4` then load that in Android, if it ends `.flv` then it wont play with just Android SDK code. Here I think the link server type is RTMP so its protected. Not looking good. Protected server + wrong video format for Android = wont work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with a videoView :)